# Problem with alpha testers in action on google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a problem with Action on google and my alpha test users.
I am using the API-V2,  when I use my app in a test mode, with the simulator or with my google home linked with my dev account everything works fine and I don't have any problem. I can invoke my app and use it normaly (every intent works perfectly).

But, I want to test my app with alpha test users, so I added some test accounts in the alpha testers list in Actions on Google console.
I sent the Opt-in Link to my users, they can accept to be alpha testers and they can launch the agent with the Invocation sample.

The Welcome intent launch is ok and then the problem appears:
My fullfillment cloud function is not called with alpha tester, only the Default Fallback Intent is launched ?!?! and I don't know why :(
The same input with dev account works fine.

I don't know what to do, the only solution I have today is to give the login and the password of my dev account to my testers. You will agree that this not the best solution.

Did I miss something ? Please help me ! :)

Thanks

Comment: Are the test account regular Gmail or Gsuite (enterprise) accounts?

Comment: The test account are Gmail accounts